# Access sharppoint online rest apis via external gmail user

Tags: sharepoint-online

Really need your help here. struggling with this for almost a week and still have not found how to do it.

Get access denied all the time.

Browser scenario works for me

I have a gmail user let's name it testuser@gmail.com which is registered in sharepoint and have permissions to access a site.

In the browser, when I enter https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/subSite2  it uses Ouath2, it prompts me to select the user

I select testuser@gmail.com and then it signs me in.

Then I run the following sharepoint rest api https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/subSite2/_api/web and it works!!!

I have no problem with none external users, I use the https://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/

article and all works!!.

For external user I understand that I need to use the Oauth2 authentication.

I have an app registered in Azure AD with Sharepoint Sites.Read.All and Sites.Search.All.

I'm using java, and I tried to do it with code with all possible oauth2 authentication flows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows), using MSAL and ADAL.

I pass the client id and secret and manage to login, but when I run the rest api with the required headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token_access>
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata
```

I get:
`{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}`

Can anyone give me a clue how to do this?? This is the list of stuff I tried:

https://www.advaiya.com/blog/access-sharepoint-rest-api-using-oauth/

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Scenarios

Download the samples and none of it work for me

https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf
(but this does not include using a user :( )

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you go for SharePoint App registration:

> https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
>   [image: SharePoint Application Registration Page]

, which basically involves creating an app and assigning permissions:

> https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
>   [image]

Permission XML Sample:

```
    <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
       <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" 
        Right="FullControl"/>
    </AppPermissionRequests>
```

and then trusting the app in SharePoint? 
Then you can use generated client  id and secret to get the access token that is further used in Authorization headers for SharePoint rest API requests.